# How do I write a XPath with qualified name with Perl's XML::LibXML?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I've found this on http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=606909

> looking by qualified name ...
>   In this case you can call findnodes method on any node, you don't need the XML::LibXML::XPathContext with its prefix => namespace mapping:
>   $doc->findnodes('//*/info/fooTransaction/transactionDetail/*[name() = "histFile:transactionSummary"]/*');

In which way I have to edit my xpath to get my script working without XPathContext?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; use strict;
use 5.012;
use XML::LibXML;


my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
$parser->recover_silently( 1 );

my $doc = $parser->parse_file( 'http://www.heise.de/' );

my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $doc->getDocumentElement );
$xc->registerNs( 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' );

my $nodes = $xc->findnodes( '//xmlns:h2/xmlns:a' );
for my $node ( $nodes->get_nodelist ) {
    say $_->getName, '=', $_->getValue for $node->attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the same model as given in the article. If you want to test the textual name of the node, instead of considering what URI the node's namespace is mapped to, then call [`name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name) and do a string comparison.

```
//*[name() = "xmlns:h2"]/*[name() = "xmlns:a"]
```

For that expression to match anything, though, there would need to be nodes in the document literally named `xmlns:h2`. You'd need to have a document like this:

```
<xmlns:h2>
  <xmlns:a>header</xmlns:a>
</xmlns:h2>
```

The page you've linked to doesn't look like that, though. It uses ordinary HTML node names like `h2` and `a`, not `xmlns:h2`. The simple names are indeed in the `xmlns` namespace, but only because that's configured as the default namespace for the document. Since the nodes aren't named with a namespace prefix, don't include that prefix in your name strings:

```
//*[name() = "h2"]/*[name() = "a"]
```

A further change you could make, in case *some* nodes use the `xmlns` prefix when others don't, is to use [`local-name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name) instead of `name`; then it will strip any namespace prefix that's present.

```
//*[local-name() = "h2"]/*[local-name() = "a"]
```

Comment: I tried this but I suppose this is not the way it works:

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;   
my $doc = $parser->parse_file( 'http://www.heise.de/' );   
my $nodes = $doc->findnodes( '//*[name() = "xmlns:h2"]' );   
say $_->nodeName for $nodes->get_nodelist;

Comment: Reading foreign language is not the same as reading first language:
"Since the nodes aren't named with a namespace prefix, don't include that prefix in your name strings"

Comment: The names of the nodes in your Web site are just `a` and `html`. The names in the XML you're parsing do not include the namespace prefix `xmlns`. The original XPath expression checks whether the `name()` function returns the string `xmlns:a`, but that is not the node's name, so the comparison fails. The name is just `a`; it includes no prefix for the XML namespace.